# Migrate multiple notebooks from current environment to new environment

Tags: migration, databricks, databricks-unity-catalog, azure-notebooks

I am trying to migrate multiple notebooks from current environment to new UC enabled environment.

I am looking for a solution where I can migrate groups of notebooks or a each folder of notebooks from one environment to anothe.

I tried to download a folder of notebooks and upload it didnot replicate as is.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps to Enable your workspace for Unity Catalog

To enable an existing workspace:

As an account admin, log in to the account console.
**Step 1:** Click Catalog icon Catalog.

[image]

**Step 2:** Click the metastore name.

**Step 3:** Click the Workspaces tab.

**Step 4:** Click Assign to workspaces.
Select one or more workspaces. You can type part of the workspace name to filter the list.
Click Assign.

**Step 5:** On the confirmation dialog, click Enable.

**Reference:**
[Effective Migration to Unity Catalog: A Guide](https://www.tredence.com/blog/migrating-to-unity-catalog#)

[Unity catalog Migration](https://community.databricks.com/t5/get-started-discussions/unity-catalog-migration/td-p/54814)

[Enable a workspace for Unity Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/enable-workspaces)